# How to use msoShapeStylePresetXX in Shape.ShapeStyle

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, excel-interop

How can I access msoShapeStylePresetXX in Shape.ShapeStyle?

Im using Visual studio 2012 Visual Basic and Excel (2013 or lower version)

I want to use msoShapeStylePresetXX as a shape style on my shape

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'AccessdbtestDataSet.country' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.CountryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.AccessdbtestDataSet.country)
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection
        Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM  country"
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=accessdbtest.accdb"
        con.Open()
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim ds As New DataSet

        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(query, con)
        da.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        con.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer
        Dim xlCenter As String = "center"

        xlApp = New Excel.ApplicationClass
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")



        xlWorkSheet.Range("A1:D1").MergeCells = True
        xlWorkSheet.Range("A2:D2").MergeCells = True
        xlWorkSheet.Range("A3:D3").MergeCells = True
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Republic of the Philippines"
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(2, 1) = "NCR"
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(3, 1) = "Manila"
        xlWorkSheet.Range("A1:A1").HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter
        xlWorkSheet.Range("A2:A2").HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter
        xlWorkSheet.Range("A3:A3").HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter
        For i = 5 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 2
            For j = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = _
                    DataGridView1(j, i - 3).Value.ToString()
            Next
        Next


        xlApp.Range("A4").Select()
        xlApp.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

        Dim shp As Excel.Shape
        Dim clLeft As Double
        Dim clTop As Double
        Dim clWidth As Double
        Dim clHeight As Double

        Dim cl As Excel.Range
        ''Dim shpOval As Excel.Shape
        xlApp.Range("G5").Select()

        cl = xlApp.Range(xlApp.Selection.Address)  '<-- Range("C2")

        clLeft = cl.Left
        clTop = cl.Top
        clHeight = cl.Height
        clWidth = cl.Width

        shp = xlApp.ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(1, clLeft, clTop, 100, 100)

        //This line of code is my problem <----------------------------<|
        shp.ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePresetXX


        Debug.Print(shp.Left = clLeft)
        Debug.Print(shp.Top = clTop)

        xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("C:\excel\vbexcel.xlsx")
        xlWorkBook.Close()
        xlApp.Quit()

        releaseObject(xlApp)
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)

        MsgBox("You can find the file C:\vbexcel.xlsx")
    End Sub

    Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
        Try
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
            obj = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            obj = Nothing
        Finally
            GC.Collect()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add a reference to the "**office.dll**" in your project (like you did for Excel with `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`).

With that, VB.net should show you the msoXXX constants:

[image]